# swap div on timer

Tags: javascript, css

I have 2 DIV's is the same place absolutely positioned. I want to show one for 10 seconds and then hide it and show the other and so on. But not quite sure how to go about it.
Thanks

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>


#div1 {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
}

#div2 {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(ToggleDiv, 10000);
});
function ToggleDiv(){
    $(#div1).toggle();
    $(#div2).toggle();
}
</script>
```

Comment: In the `setInterval`, you don't want to put ToggleDiv in quotes. Just put the bare word in there. Also probably want to note that this is a jQuery solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the javascript to use so you don't have to download an entire Javascript library for just a few lines of code. Just put it right before your `</body>` tag.

```
var d1 = document.getElementById('div1'), d2 = document.getElementById('div2');
function toggle(){
    var showDiv1 = d1.style.display === 'none';
    d1.style.display = showDiv1 ? 'block' : 'none';
    d2.style.display = showDiv1 ? 'none' : 'block';
}
setInterval(toggle, 10000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css animation

```css
#div1 {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
z-index:2;
animation: A 20s linear infinite;
}
#div2 {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
top: 0;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
background: blue;
z-index:1;
animation: B 20s linear infinite;
}
@keyframes A{50%{z-index:1;}}
@keyframes B{50%{z-index:2;}}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
```